# Reverse foreach XML nodes in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm adding related elements (Parent-Child) through an XML file using the following:

```
[xml]$fileXml = Get-Content 'c:\example.xml'

$fileXml.Elements | % {
  MyAdd-Function $_
}
```

When deleting these elements, how do I make sure it iterates in the reverse order? I've tried this and it doesn't work:

```
[xml]$fileXml = Get-Content 'c:\example.xml'

[Array]::Reverse($fileXml.Elements) | % {
  MyRemove-Function $_
}
```

I'm thinking about turning `$fileXml.Elements` into an actual array and then reversing, but I was wondering if there's an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach sounds good to me, but considering that `Reverse()` doesn't return an array, you would have to split `Reverse()` and `Foreach-Object`.

```
PS > [array]::Reverse.OverloadDefinitions
static void Reverse(array array)
```

I'm not sure where you got the `Elements`-property from, but here's a PoC:

```
PS > $xml = [xml]@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<note>
<to>User1</to>
</note>
<note>
<to>User2</to>
</note>
</root>
"@

#Store the elements in an array 
PS > $a = $xml.root.note
PS > $a | % { $_.to }

User1
User2

#Reverse
PS > [array]::Reverse($a)
PS > $a | % { $_.to }

User2
User1
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked! I guess I need to store it into a variable first c: